# Flutter - how to call child widget's method from parent

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Let's say we have two stateful **widgets**.

```
ParentWidget(){

}

ChildWidget() {
  someMethod(){
    // some code, for example setState code
  }

}
```

Now when I use the `ChildWidget` in `ParentWidget`, how do I call the `someMethod()`?

Comment: Just wanted to note - even though the answers below are good - you should not be doing this in the first place. This is an anti-pattern in flutter.

Comment: I have a reusable button widget that changes to spinner and back to button. How else do I implement it?

Comment: You create a stateless Child widget, and in constructor you set if it is Spinner or button. Something like ````ChildWidget() { ChildWidget(bool spinner)...````. When you need to flip from spinner to button (or back) you just rebuild with the new widget. You don't go telling widget to change - you create a new one.

Comment: but that will rebuild all other widgets in the parent class, but with what I am trying only the button widget will be rebuild inside of itself

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem - Flutter is designed for the fast rebuild. I agree with you in a way that calling a method from the child may be needed for performance - but unless you really encounter performance issue, I'd do it the correct way.
Other option is to go with Provider/Consumer approach. This is still 'correct' Flutter way, and you would get your granular tree rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is way what I've used.

- Make a GlobalKey instance
- Pass the Globalkey as a Key parameter to child widget.
- Call GlobalKey.currentState.method();

```
ParentWidget(){
   GlobalKey<ChildWidgetState> globalKey = GlobalKey();
   ChildWidget(key: globalKey);

   ...

   globalKey.currentState.someMethod();


}

ChildWidget() {
  ChildWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  someMethod(){
    // some code, for example setState code
  }

}
```

TestCode

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  GlobalKey<ChildWidgetState> globalKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            globalKey.currentState.someMethod();
          },
          child: Text('ParentWidget'),
        ),

        ChildWidget(key: globalKey),
      ],
    );
  }
}


class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ChildWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  ChildWidgetState createState() => ChildWidgetState();
  
}

class ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  void someMethod() {
    print('someMethod is called');
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('childWidget');
  }
}
```

**edit:** this approach works, but thanks @Andrija for pointing this out:

> Just wanted to note - even though the answers below are good - you
> should not be doing this in the first place. This is an anti-pattern
> in flutter.

Comment: your code produces next error: The method 'someMethod' isn't defined for the type 'State' in here `globalKey.currentState.someMethod();`

Comment: I fixed code. The problem is that when define GlobalKey, need to give a ChildWidgetState type. 'GlobalKey<ChildWidgetState> globalKey = GlobalKey()'

Answer (score 2):

If you need call function on widget you can use:

```
context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<T>()
```

If you need call function on state of that widget you can use:

```
context.findRootAncestorStateOfType<T>();
```

read more at:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/findAncestorWidgetOfExactType.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/findRootAncestorStateOfType.html